# With paypal to take care of payment transactions, should I worry about anything else?

Tags: web-applications, paypal

I'm having payment transactions in my site. To handle that I link my users to paypal site. Since the security of the payment process is taken care of by PayPal,  is there anything else that I need to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

Depends, one should always worry about site security.  You have to deal with price changes, sql injections, and user account hijacking. Then the actual security of the box hosting the site. Alot to worry about actually.